# Quarkus log output when running tests in Maven

Tags: java, maven, logging, quarkus, maven-surefire-plugin

If I run unit tests for Quarkus from inside Eclipse, the Eclipse console view shows Quarkurs' log output. However, when I run the same tests in Maven, the Quarkus output is completely swallowed and does not appear anywhere. If there is a test failure due to an exception in the application code I get the test failure message but I cannot see what actually went wrong inside the application. The Java log manager is configured to use JBoss logging by using the surefire system property.
Does anyone know where one can find the Quarkus log output or how it can be enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't posted any code or configuration files, so there is no way to know what may be causing your problem.

Potentially you may want to check out a few things:

- In the application configuration file, make sure *quarkus.log.console.enable* is set to **true** (if you can't find it don't worry about it, since by default it's **true**)
- Is *quarkus.log.file.enable* set to **true**? (by default it's **false**)

While I can't tell you what the problem is exactly, since there is no code to review, I will put links to the official Quarkus logging guide. What may interest you is under [Runtime configuration](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#runtime-configuration) and [Logging configuration reference](https://quarkus.io/guides/logging#loggingConfigurationReference).

Comment: The problem is not logging as such. It works perfectly when running as a standalone application and when running tests from within Eclipse. Therefore I assume that the log configuration is correct. Just when tests are run in Maven Surefire the console output just vanishes. What kind of "code" do you expect me to show?

Comment: If that is the case you should check out the [surefire documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/). It explains everything pretty well. From where the log files are generated, to configuration using different testing frameworks . When I meant "code", I was referring to the application configuration or the surefire configuration inside the pom.xml file :).